# matlab make IF decide writing someting inside a function

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have these unknowns and equations: u1,u2,...u10 and eq1,eq2,...eq10.
I am currently solving them using vpasolve
Usually they are worth calculating, but sometimes their values are so low (<0.0001) that I would like to eliminate them, and after vpasolve solves the rest (some 10 minutes) I should verify if it was wrong or not to eliminate the unknowns.

So this would mean something like:

```
verif=zeros(10); %false value for removing unknowns
syms if verif(1)=0
write 'u1'
end
```

... and so on for every 10 unknowns.
`vpasolve` would have a similar way of deciding if the unknowns and equations are written.
This is the place that I should check it removing was OK. And this is the place where the <0.0001 decision is made:

```
if u1<0.0001
verif(1)=1;
```

My problem is that I don't know how to correctly write the first code and how to do it more easily for 100 unknowns (something like a for loop).

EDIT 1
This is all inside a for loop.

EDIT 2

I have spoken to a Java developer and he explained to me that some things are not possible (or should be avoided) because of the way matlab works.

The conclusion was that I should prepare the equations `vpasolve` needs elsewhere, not with an `if` within it.

So this is how it looks like now, please say if there is something else wrong that I cannot see (I am just a chemist):

```
verif=zeros(10); %false value for removing unknowns
eq=[eq1,eq2...eq10]; %original eq's
eq(2,:)=eq(1,:); %eq's I can modify
for loop
syms u1 u2...u10;
[u1,u2...u10]=vpasolve(eq(2,:),[u1,u2...u10];
%this is where the verification of my assumption should take place
%to note that u1...u4 are not to be judged this way
if verif(5)=1
%the verification I need
if %verification returns that the assumption was wrong-this normally does not happen
eq(2,5)=eq(1,5);
verif(5)=0; %wait a few loops before making that assumption again
run the for loop again
end
end
...
if u5<0,0001
eq(2,5)=(u5==0);
verif(5)=1;
end
...
end for
```

And a question about my other questions that suffer from the same problem... should I delete them, or place a link to here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after rearranging things it looks like this:

init5

```
om(1)=2.76;           %conc acid baie
om(2)=27.5/56;        %conc Fe2 baie
om(3)=23.5/56;        %conc Fe3 baie
om(4)=1;              %conc baza biureta
om(5)=5/1000;         %volum acid luat in pahar
om(6)=50/1000;        %volumul la care se aduce solutia din pahar
om(7)=1/1000;         %volumul de baza adaugat pt iteratie- va disparea cand se va autorecalcula sau va deveni v initial si va varia

digits(6)
vb0max=uint8((om(1)+om(3))*10);              %volum baza pt titrare     acid (fara Fe)-se va sterge pt ca se va face altfel
cct(1)=om(1)*om(5)/om(6);                    %conc constanta 1 -     acid dupa dilutie   

%1-H^+  2-Fe^2+  3-Fe^3+  4-SO4^2-  5-HSO4^-  6-FeHSO4^+  7-FeSO4  8-FeHSO4^2+  9-FeSO4^+  10-Fe(SO4)2^-  11-FeOH^2+  12-Fe(OH)2^+  13-Fe(OH)3???0  14-OH^-  15-Na+
c=zeros(15,vb0max);
ct=zeros(4,vb0max);      %matricea conc totale in timp real  4-OH
v=zeros(4,vb0max);       %matricea volume in timp real  1-vt  2-vb  3-v1  4-v3

%concentratii totale
v(1,1)=om(6);
ct(1,1)=2*cct(1);
ct(2,1)=om(2)*om(5)/v(1,1);
ct(3,1)=om(3)*om(5)/v(1,1);
cct(4)=(cct(1)+ct(2,1)+3/2*ct(3,1))*om(6);

t = animatedline;
axis([0,vb0max+1,0,7])
```

func5
    r=sym('r',[1 12]);

```
eq=[ct(1,j)-r(5)-r(6)-r(8)      , 0, 0.5, 0, 0;
ct(2,j)-r(6)-r(7)           , NaN, NaN, 0, 0;
ct(3,j)-r(8)-r(9)-r(10)-r(11)-r(12) , NaN, NaN, 0, 0;
cct(4)/v(1,j)-r(5)-r(6)-r(7)-r(8)-r(9)-2*r(10), NaN, NaN, 0, 0;
r(4)*r(1)*10^1.98           , NaN, NaN, 0, 0;
r(4)*r(1)*r(2)*10^1.08      , NaN, NaN, 0, 0;
r(4)*r(2)*10^2.25           , NaN, NaN, 0, 0;
r(4)*r(1)*r(3)*10^2.48      , NaN, NaN, 0, 0;
r(4)*r(3)*10^4.04           , NaN, NaN, 0, 0;
r(4)^2*r(3)*10^5.38         , NaN, NaN, 0, 0;
1.9*10^(-3)*r(3)/r(1)       , NaN, NaN, 0, 0;
2.5*10^(-3)*r(3)/r(1)^2     , NaN, NaN, 0, 0];
eq(:,6)=eq(:,1);

r = vpasolve(r==transpose(eq(:,6)), r,eq(:,2:3));

%verify
for i=5:12
if isequal(eq(i,4),1)
if eq(i,6)>0.0001
eq(i,4)=0;
eq(i,6)=eq(i,1);
%redo vpasolve
end
end
end

%for i=5:12
%if r1<0,00001
%eq(i,6)=0
%eq(i,4)=1
%if r1<0
%end
%end

c(1,j)=r.r1;c(2,j)=r.r2;c(3,j)=r.r3;c(4,j)=r.r4;c(5,j)=r.r5;c(6,j)=r.r6;c(7,j)=r.r7;c(8,j)=r.r8;c(9,j)=r.r9;c(10,j)=r.r10;c(11,j)=r.r11;c(12,j)=r.r12;
```

sorry about commented lines, they are not done, but main problem of question (and other past questions) is solved

and main program

```
init5
for j=1:vb0max
func5
v(1,j+1)=v(1,j)+om(7);  %v total
v(2,j+1)=v(2,j)+om(7);  %vb
ct(1,j+1)=(ct(1,j)*v(1,j)-om(4)*om(7))/v(1,j+1);
ct(3,j+1)=ct(3,j)*v(1,j)/v(1,j+1);
ct(2,j+1)=ct(2,j)*v(1,j)/v(1,j+1);
ct(4,j)=10^(-14)/ct(1,j);  %OH t
pH(j)=-log10(ct(1,j));addpoints(t,v(2,j)*1000,pH(j));drawnow
pause(0.05)
end
```